# Autoplay embed video added from core Media module

Tags: 8, media

Is it possible to, somehow, enable embed video autoplay for a field added form Media module?
For example media type "Video" has this option, but type "Remote video" doesn't.
  [image: Media video autoplay]
Embed video field is rendered as iframe in iframe, so javascript access to second iframe is limited, if I'm correct.